# Dropbox 'Copy Public Link' in Thunar file manager (Xfce)

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, dropbox, thunar

I'm using XUbuntu and was a bit saddened that I couldn't use Dropbox within Thunar file manager.

Can I make a custom context menu option to 'copy public link' in Thunar?

Comment: [there's a way of limiting the option to just the public folder](http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201207/page13.html) > Thanks to the dropbox.py script, it knows if you are in Dropbox’s Public folder or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This solution](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/how-to-install-dropbox-in-xubuntu-and.html) works for me:

1. Install nautilus-dropbox (yes, it uses Nautilus, but we will integrate it in Thunar at step 4)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
   ```
2. Start Dropbox daemon:

   ```
   ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
   ```
3. Add Dropbox to start-up:

   Settings Manager > Session and Startup > Applications Autostart > Add

   under "Name", enter "Dropbox"

   under "Command", enter "/home/USERNAME/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd"
4. Install the Dropbox Thunar extension: [32bit](http://packages.crunchbang.org/waldorf/pool/main/thunar-dropbox-plugin_0.2.0-1_i386.deb), [64bit](http://packages.crunchbang.org/waldorf/pool/main/thunar-dropbox-plugin_0.2.0-1_amd64.deb) or [source](http://softwarebakery.com/maato/thunar-dropbox.html)

For me, it works like a charm, except that, when I click to "Open Dropbox Folder" from Dropbox panel applet, it opens Nautilus instead of Thunar.

edit: It is also useful to add a Dropbox folder link to Thunar's sidebar. This can be done simply by draging-'n'-droping Dropbox folder to the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks for this. I must have been extremely inefficient on Google earlier, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 8):

First you need to install xclip, `sudo apt-get install xclip`

Now in Thunar click Edit>Configure custom actions, then click the green plus sign.

Under **Name** enter 'Copy Public Link', or something suited to yourself

Under **Command** enter `dropbox puburl %f | xclip -se c`

In the same window, under the **Appearance Conditions** tab, tick everything.

Now if you right click in Thunar you will see the dropbox option, I'd like to know if there's a way of limiting the option to **just** the public folder, that way it won't constantly be there in places it isn't needed.

Comment: Though you can use `dropbox puburl` **only** in your Public folder, anywhere else you will get an error like `Couldn't get public url: Unknown Error` , thumbsup for this answer.